# Has DevExtreme DxDataGrid support for OData in Blazor?

Tags: odata, devexpress, blazor

I'm trying to test this feature, I see in the documentation how to use OData in Razor, but not in Blazor. It's OData suported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DxDataGrid component is obsolete, so I decided to post a solution for the newest DxGrid component.

We published a new step-by-step tutorial and runnable sample on GitHub:
[How to Create a Web API Service Backend for a Blazor WebAssembly Application with DevExpress Blazor Components](https://www.devexpress.com/go/XAF_Security_NonXAF_Blazor_WebAssembly.aspx). The backend uses EF Core for data access and is powered by the free [DevExpress Web API Service](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/application_framework/security-web-api-service.xml) for CRUD and authorization.

The application works with blog post data. It authenticates a user with cookies, determines his or her permissions, and selectively enables the following data operations:

- Lists existing Post records
- Displays a photo of a Post author
- Creates new Post records
- Archives a Post record
- Displays a report based on Post records

To bind data from OData/Web API to the [DxGrid](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.DxGrid) component, our example implements a [GridCustomDataSource](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.GridCustomDataSource) descendant powered by [Simple.OData.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Simple.OData.Client/) (MIT). We used this open source library instead of the standard [Microsoft OData client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/using-blazor-wasm-with-odata-client) because the latter had a known issue (https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/1970), which prevented normal operation in Blazor WebAssembly at the time of testing.

**Search keywords:** RBAC, Access Control, Authentication, Authorization, OData, Swagger, OpenAPI, Web API, ASP.NET Core, Blazor, WebAssembly, WASM, EF Core, EF, Entity Framework

Answer (score 1):

I was trying the same thing, and apparently is not supported out of the box, but there's a workaround:

```
// Step 1: Add the nuget package Microsoft.OData.Client to the Blazor project.
```

```
// Step 2: Implement ODataAsyncAdapter
public class ODataAsyncAdapter : DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.Async.IAsyncAdapter
{
    private HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public Task<int> CountAsync(IQueryProvider queryProvider, Expression expr, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        DataServiceQueryProvider provider = (DataServiceQueryProvider)queryProvider;
        DataServiceQuery query = (DataServiceQuery)provider.CreateQuery(expr);
        return this.httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<int>(query.RequestUri.ToString(), cancellationToken);
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<T>> ToEnumerableAsync<T>(IQueryProvider queryProvider, Expression expr, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        DataServiceQueryProvider provider = (DataServiceQueryProvider)queryProvider;
        return ((DataServiceQuery<T>)provider.CreateQuery<T>(expr)).ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

```
// Step 3: Register the ODataAsyncAdapter
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.Async.CustomAsyncAdapters.RegisterAdapter(typeof(DataServiceQueryProvider), new ODataAsyncAdapter());
}
```

```
// Final Step: In the Grid.razor page
<DxDataGrid T="@UserDto" CustomData="@this.LoadCustomData" ShowFilterRow="true" PageSize="10" KeyFieldName="@nameof(UserDto.Id)">
    <Columns>
        <DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(UserDto.Id)" />
        <DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(UserDto.Name)" />
    </Columns>
</DxDataGrid>

@code
{
    protected async Task<LoadResult> LoadCustomData(DataSourceLoadOptionsBase options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        options.AllowAsyncOverSync = false;
        return await DataSourceLoader.LoadAsync(this.ODataService.CreateQuery<UserDto>("UserDto"), options, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

PS: I will try to simplify somethings, them I'll edit this anwser.